# How to distinguish a relative location?

Tags: prepositions

Yesterday I wondered "Why is "get home" used without preposition?" and found [the following](https://www.italki.com/question/248417?hl=ru). According to the answer there are two types of location: relative and (perhaps) absolute. But I couldn't understand why the "home" is relative, since it is a concrete building, flat or place. Likewise i could use "working office" as relative, because it can be a particular place today and another one tomorrow (in case of changing job).

How can I distinguish 'relative' places from other? Or how can I find out that a subject (location) shoud be used without a preposition after verbs "get/go"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is an excellent answer [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33652/why-is-to-not-used-before-home) at our sister site.

Comment: **home** is an (intransitive) adposition :)   "go home" is analogous to "go along" and "get home" is analogous to "get along".  come home, to come along.

Comment: Compare:  *His house is **to the right** of us, so you must **turn right** at the next intersection.*

Comment: So, **right** is sometimes a place or location or area, and sometimes a direction.  The same is true with **home**. Sometimes it is a place, and sometimes it is a direction (and means *homeward*).

Answer (score 1):

Here it seems to work like an adverb of direction: "there" or "east(ward)" or "back".

> Go home, get home, drive home, bike home
>
> Go there, get there, drive there, bike there

Etc.

This of course doesn't preclude the existence of a separate lexeme "home" as a common noun ("my home", "the homes").

Incidentally, "home" functions oddly in many languages, as do many words describing our earliest and commonest experiences.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that link is correct... "home" is relative because it might be my home, and it might be your home. If I say "I'm going home" the implication is that it's my home I'm talking about. Whose home it is is relative to the speaker.

But, "the office" is also relative to the speaker. I could say, when I'm going to where I work, "I'm going to the office". The implication is that it's the office I work at, not the only office that exists. I also would not say "I'm going office".